# VS Gallery don't validate my VSIX extension

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I developed a Project Template for/with Visual Studio 2017. This extension does work as expected when I debug it.

I now try to add it in Visual Studio Gallery but the website does not validate my extension. I just get a generic error message : "Invalid model file in VSIX" (maybe poorly translated from French)

Is there any way to prevalidate my VSIX with a tool or get more information about what is wrong with my extension?

Thanks

Comment: Dou you upload using new or old portal? I have very similar issue.. they are in the process of migration as of my understanding. Important- extension should have VSIX 3 format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that VS Gallery does not support VSIX that targets explicitly framework 4.6.2

Targeting 4.6 only did the trick